# WKWebView PDF Pinning On Rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am working on a project that is using WKWebView to view PDF files but there's an issue with multiple-page PDF file.

When on rotation from Landscape to Portrait or vice versa, the WKWebView seems to lose focus on that very page i.e it's a bit off from the exact position of the PDF document that was under view after rotation.

Any hint to solve this issue ?

Comment: Which language are you using? Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Its written in Objective-C but if there's a Swift solution then its good too